# Flutter credentials returning null whereas sign in successful

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using flutter firebase authentication services but I can't get credentials here's my sign in code using Email password authentication

```
try {
  setState(() => isLoading = true);
  final credential = await FirebaseAuth
      .instance
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email!, password: password!);
  print((credential.credential ?? null)
      .toString());
  if (mounted) {
    Provider.of<UserCredentialsProvider>(
            context,
            listen: false)
        .setUser(credential);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    SimpleUtilities().errorSnackBar(context,
        snackbarData:
            'No user linked with this email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    SimpleUtilities().errorSnackBar(context,
        snackbarData:
            'Wrong password provided.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  SimpleUtilities().errorSnackBar(context,
      snackbarData: e.toString());
}
```

However, my problem is that `print((credential.credential ?? null).toString());` statement returns null. As a result I can't use accesstoken for the user. However, its not caught in any of the catch blocks but sign in is successful.

Here's my console log:

```
I/FirebaseAuth(12710): Logging in as name@mail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
2
W/System  (12710): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(12710): Notifying id token listeners about user ( kNsqWnnr0Wg0E5Ue46CwckfXjIk1 ).
I/flutter (12710): null
```

I've checked all all the integration steps on firebase console use is added and login event is registered
[Firebase console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0SWR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: When you sign in to Firebase with email+password it only generates an ID token and a refresh token for that user. No OAuth2 access token is generated in this scenario, as there is no OAuth flow that gets executed.

When I reproduce the same flow with the native JavaScript SDK [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/auth-v9-signinwithemailandpassword?file=index.js), there *is* a property `accessToken` under `stsTokenManager` in the response, its value is just a copy of the ID token as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

---

I initially thought this was a bug, so filed [issue #10798](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10798) for it on the FlutterFire GitHub repo. There's some good discussion there too now, especially on my initial misunderstanding. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution Much appreciated.  

Leaving below for other devs:
Here's the code for this token in Flutter:
`await credential.user!.getIdToken()`

Comment: Aha, so you're looking for the ID token? Note that that is quite different (and much easier to find :) than the access token.

Comment: yes. Some people call it a session token. I don't actually know what Firebase uses the term for it.